# document.location.href='#location'; vs. $.mobile.changePage('#location');

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

What is the difference between these two redirrections? I've got an application, which works correctly on chrome and android 4, when I use, but not on android 2.x.x

```
document.location.href='#location';
```

But when I use

```
$.mobile.changePage('#location');
```

it does not work correctly neither in chrome nor in android. Redirrection seems to happen, but then immediately after that it jumps to the index page of my application.

Comment: See this: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: Android 2.1-2.3 should have A-grade support.

Comment: are you using any transition effect while calling `$.mobile.changePage('#location');` function

Comment: See this : http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 2):

`$.mobile.changePage` is jQM style method for navigation. Meaning that if you have AJAX navigation enabled (it's enabled by default), page you linked to will be fetched asynchronously and injected into DOM of current page.

This is done by fetching target page, scanning it for jQM page (container element with `data-role='page'`), injecting that element into current DOM and displays it, while hiding previous content.

Check [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html) for more details.

Make sure that

- your target page has a jQuery Mobile page
- target page is fetched by jQM (using Fiddler or similar tool)
- that it exists in DOM of current page

You may also decide to disable AJAX navigation (which is wrong idea when developing mobile applications). This is done by setting `ajaxEnabled` to false in `mobileinit` handler. For more details check [jQM configuration documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html). Make sure that your `mobileinit` hook is executed before you include jquery-mobile.js in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#location", {
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
});
```

jQuery Mobile exposes several [**methods**](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) and properties on the $.mobile object for use in your applications.

Comment: it works just like $.mobile.changePage('#location'); just shows the transition before jumping to the index page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the document is ready before using `$.mobile.changepage` otherwise it will not work. This will be a issue if you are using automatic redirect to a different page after some event on a given page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.mobile.changepage('xyz.html');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
               if(//url filtering){ 
                   view.loadUrl(url);
               }
                return true;
            }
        });
```