# jQuery Mobile “Error Loading Page”

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery1.8.2 and Jquery-mobile 1.1

When i click on Logout button i have to goto the Home page. I am able get the home page but before going back to the home page got the **"Error Loading Page"** message.

Test.html

```
<body>  
  <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
          <h1> Success Page </h1>
           <a data-role="button" id="logoutbtn" data-theme="b">Logout</a>
       </div><!-- /header -->
       <div data-role='content'>            
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#logoutbtn").click(function () {     
    document.location.href = "Home.html";
});
});
```

Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Dipaks

Instead of

```
document.location.href = "/Home.html";
```

I have modified it as like below

```
document.location.href = "./Home.html";
```

Its working fine and able to go back to home page with out any error.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using the jquery mobile specific methods.

```
$.mobile.changePage("Home.html");
```

See [document-location-href-location-vs-mobile-changepagelocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823386/document-location-href-location-vs-mobile-changepagelocation)

Answer (score 1):

`$.mobile.changePage("Home.html")` did not work on my PC

but instead `$.mobile.changePage("#");` works and it's hiding the `error loading page` message.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the right versions and $.mobile.changePage to change a page and it still failed with the same error. Later I realized that I was doing this in a js file in www/js/custom/handler/handler.js. So I was using paths relative to this location.

However later I realized that the path has to be relative to index.html that includes this js.

That resolved my issue.